# Is it legal to use a WordPress plugin which clones Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, copyright

I wanted to make a website where users/visitors and come and ask question and get answers. Very similar to what we have here on Stack Overflow, but I want that for a local regional problems/queries.

I am planning to use Wordpress for this. I came across [a plugin](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/qa-wordpress-questions-and-answers-plugin) whose demo you can see at:

http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/qa-wordpress-questions-and-answers-plugin

Now I really liked the plugin, before I use it I wanted to know if this is legal?

I have seen the **"site design / logo © 2012 stack exchange inc"** in the footer of stack overflow site which made me rethink about this.

I mean I won't have any copyright problems right?

Comment: Ignore my off-topic vote, I did not read to the last sentence.

Comment: **Strongly related** [Wordpress Q&A plugin blatantly ripping off Stack Overflow design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88870/wordpress-qa-plugin-blatently-ripping-off-stack-overflow-design) (spoiler, yep - same plugin). It was originally a _carbon_ copy, but they've changed it since.

Comment: Hi Tim, nice read back there, so now with what they have changed, is it okay and legal to use it ?

Comment: @Yasser I can't provide an official response to that, I'm not an employee of Stack Exchange. I just linked it in case people forgot that this keeps coming up :)

Comment: @TimPost yes that right! Lets hope some official spokeperson from stack exchange answers this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the CSS, javascript & other aspects of the plugin are their own (not copied from Stack Overflow), I think it is legal. There are many [clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267/172552) of Stack Overflow out there

It is possible that it's copied, because I see that tags are exactly copied.